# Screens shared in multiple screens disappear after deactivation in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: caliburn.micro

I've run across an issue using Caliburn.Micro when sharing a `Screen` between multiple parent Screens. In this example I have 2 tabs inside a shell. Each tab shares a single instance of `SharedViewModel` (essentially a singleton).

```
var shared = new SharedViewModel();

Items.AddRange(new []
{
    new TabViewModel { Shared = shared },
    new TabViewModel { Shared = shared },
});
```

And each tab's view has a `ContentControl` bound to the `Shared` property which is `SharedViewModel`:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Shared}"/>
```

Here's the order of events:

1. Start the app. See the shared view.
2. Switch to second tab. See the shared view.
3. Switch back to first tab. **Shared view is gone.**
4. Switch to second tab again. The shared view is there.
5. Proceed to pull hair out.

You can see the example application on [my github](https://github.com/kmcginnes/PoC.CaliburnSharedViews).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Screen` class is based on `ViewAware` which caches and reuses its view once it has been loaded. As one and the same instance of a visual can't be attached to the visual tree multiple times, this leads to the behavior you're observing.

Try overriding this in your screen:

```
public override object GetView(object context = null)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, with an addendum. The `Screen` base class does not mark `GetView` as `virtual`, so you must mark the method as `new`. Thanks!

Comment: @KrisMcGinnes Actually, GetView should be defined in ViewAware as virtual, at least since version 2. Please look into https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/ViewAware.cs

Comment: Good catch. I think I was using 2.0 and not 2.0.1 which has `GetView` as virtual.