# CaliburnMicro + RowDetailsTemplate: Details-View disappears

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, caliburn.micro, rowdetailstemplate

I have a GridView which lists all my Products. The first column is a "GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn" which expands a Details-View when clicked.

I use CaliburnMicro to load the Details-View like so:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Products.View}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                 
                             EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                             ShowGroupPanel="False"
                             RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
                             RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                             cal:Message.Attach="[Event RowDetailsVisibilityChanged] = 
[Action OnRowDetailsVisibilityChanged($eventArgs)]">

<telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>  
    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding DataContext.ProductDetailsViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
   <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn />

    ...Columndefinitions...

</telerik:RadGridView>
```

I can open and close the details as long as I stay on the same product. The problem occurs if I open the details while another details is already visible. Then the details of the first disappears and never comes back. See the screenshot:
[image]

The grey box is a placeholder for the details. I opened the details of the first 8 items one after another, but only the last one is showing. My guess is that Caliburn Micro can not locate the View anymore, but I have no idea why? Because I only have one ProductDetailsViewModel?

Also: in debug mode i noticed that the "ProductDetailsViewModel"-getter is accessed only once per item after expanding the row. Collapsing and expanding the same row does not access the getter again.

UPDATE: 
Another approach, same effect: I say my ItemsSource is a collection of ProductDetailsViewModel and inherit my MainViewModel from Conductor`<ProductDetailsViewModel`>.Collection.OneActive, make the Grid binding with

```
ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}"
```

and in the xaml

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding DataContext.ActiveItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}" />
```

in the SelectionChanged I do

```
ActivateItem(e.Row.Item as ProductDetailsViewModel);
```

Same as before, the ProductDetailsView is displayed for the current item, but disappears once I show the details of another product.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the view-caching of "IViewAware", which is automatically implemented by screens. Overwriting the "GetView" in the ProductDetailsViewModel solved the issue.

Related: [Screens shared in multiple screens disappear after deactivation in Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390932/screens-shared-in-multiple-screens-disappear-after-deactivation-in-caliburn-micr)

Comment: Still not the final solution because the "old" view will not be cleaned up